# Sorting string array on priority set in excel range

Tags: vba, excel

I have two ranges A1:A5 which has the value a,b,c,d,e and B1:B5 which has 1 at B3 and 2 at B5.

I have the values of the range in string array using below code.

```
Option Base 1

Sub test()

    Dim s(5) As String
    For i = 1 To 5
        s(i) = Range("A" & i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Now I would like to sort the string array based on Column B values(Priorty) if any.

Expected result.

```
s(1)="c"
s(2)="e"
s(3)="a"
s(4)="b"
s(5)="d"
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you not use a .NET's ArrayList with a custom IComparer?

Comment: I have this requirement for excel macro so cannot use.

Comment: But can you not use either late binding or add references to mscorlib.dll for early binding? If you are working on win XP or above Windows should have .NET installed so I don't see a problem really.

Comment: @vba4all Yes, will do.

Comment: Ok, [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Implements.aspx) should give you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Base 1
Sub t()
Dim myarr() As String

With ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To 5
        ReDim Preserve myarr(i)
        myarr(i) = .Range("b" & i) & .Range("a" & i)
    Next i


For i = 1 To UBound(myarr)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(myarr)
        If myarr(i) > myarr(j) Then
            temp = myarr(i)
            myarr(i) = myarr(j)
            myarr(j) = temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(myarr)
    For j = 1 To 5
        myarr(i) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myarr(i), .Range("b" & j).Value, "")
    Next j
Next i

        .Range("c1:c5") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarr)
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have used this for my code and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Base 1

Public Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shtSourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim shtTempSheet As Worksheet
    Dim s(5) As String


    Set shtSourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet")
    Set shtTempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()

    Set rng = shtSourceSheet.Range("A1", "B5")
    rng.Copy shtTempSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rng = shtTempSheet.Range("A1", "B5")
    rng.Sort shtTempSheet.Range("B1", "B5")

    For i = 1 To 5
        s(i) = shtTempSheet.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    shtTempSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    For i = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print s(i)
    Next


End Sub
```